# Are build steps within a Jenkins Job sequential or parallel?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I am trying to figure out if within a specific Jenkins Freestyle job the build steps are executed in parallel or sequentially. I am using Jenkins to schedule some batch files, but I have some dependencies between the tables generated from one to another. I want to order them to run sequentially so that one finishes before another one starts. This might be the default, but I'm new to using Jenkins and all of my google searches have only resulted in posts about pipelines and not executing multiple build steps within a singular job.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question.
https://www.jenkins.io/pipeline/getting-started-pipelines/

The Jenkins Doc clearly mentions that

> Standard Jenkins “freestyle” jobs support simple continuous
> integration by allowing you to define sequential tasks in an
> application lifecycle.

The freestyle jobs are only meant to be used in smaller simpler CI or CD jobs. They are simple sequential steps performed one after the other.

You cannot run steps in parallel in Freestyle, though you can have conditional step execution in the freestyle job. You can have multiple Freestyle Jobs run in parallel but not a same job running multiple steps in parallel.